# Why Does printdocument print the same page when the text is changed in for loop?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Im trying to print from a datagridview each row that has 1 as one of the cells value,but right now all of them are 1(im saying this because i have an if in my loop). Im gonna take out most of the print code beacuse it prints a lot of strings, this is my printdocument.printpage.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgv.Rows(i).Cells(18).Value = 1 Then
            S_Cegnev = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            S_FullCim = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value & " " & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value & ", " & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
            S_Adoszam = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value
            S_MaganJogi = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value
            S_DatumElsodleges = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value
            S_Osszeg = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value
```

Then it draws strings using the varibles set in the for loop and compares number of 1's to no of printed pages and sets e.hasmorepages. It does print the right amount of pages, but all of them contain the data from the first row... And also the last page seems to have 2 rows of data printed on top of each other. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting the loop counter at 0 so that what will happen on every page. If you expect subsequent pages to print different rows then you need to start at a different index. You need to remember what index you finish at on one page so that you can start at the next index on the next page. That means using a variable that exists between invocations of that event handler, i.e. a member variable. You would set it to 0 before the print run and then at the end of each page.

Comment: Oh my god, of course, i even remember i had that set up last time. Thank you so much!